# Real-time jquery popup based on php return values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jgrowl

Im having a php program that will calculate the time difference and return the value in minutes.

for the message popup i use [jGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/pages/jgrowl)

so what i would like to do is get the return value and if its less than 30 minutes display the jquery message.

and most importantly it should be running live. so if a user is in a page  without navigating or refreshing, if the time is less than 30 minutes the popup should appear real-time.

can someone please suggest me how to use the return value to achieve the above requirement?

Below if the code that im using to calcutale the time differnce

```
    function time($dbtime, $currtime)
    {
        //format year-month-day hour:min:secs
        $current = strtotime($currtime);
        $indb = strtotime($dbtime);
        $minits =  round(abs($current - $indb) / 60,2);

        return $minits;
    }
```

currently im poping up only the messages on date

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        (function($){

            $(document).ready(function(){

                // jGrowl
                if ($.fn.jGrowl) {
                    // This value can be true, false or a function to be used as a callback when the closer is clciked
                            $.jGrowl.defaults.closer = function() {
                                console.log("Closing everything!", this);
                            };

                            // A callback for logging notifications.
                            $.jGrowl.defaults.log = function(e,m,o) {
                                $('#logs').append("<div><strong>#" + $(e).attr('id') + "</strong> <em>" + (new Date()).getTime() + "</em>: " + m + " (" + o.theme + ")</div>")
                            }               


                            <?php foreach ($dailies as $daily):?>
                            $.jGrowl("<?php echo $daily['calendars'][0]['Title']?>", { header: 'At <?php echo $daily['calendars'][0]['Start'];?>', sticky: true });


                            <?php endforeach;?>

                            $.jGrowl.defaults.closerTemplate = '<div>hide everything</div>';


                }

            });
        })(jQuery);

    </script>
```

Comment: Have separate PHP page returning JSON (use ```json_encode```) and then use the response object to do whatever you want to do!

Comment: @MaX could u explain a bit further please?

Comment: I don't see any code there where you're checking a value and displaying a message if it meets criteria. Where are you saving the passed time and where are you checking it? It doesn't look like you call your `time` function anywhere.

Comment: @MrOBrian  the time function returns the minutes and is accessible through $alarm->timediffn. Actually what you are asking me is what i have asked in the question. the problem is i dont know how to use the returned value to make a real time popup. i would like to know how to do the checking in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Have a php script that takes passed parameters, in this case the two times. Write the script to return the results as JSON. This is the part I assume you already have done. If you don't have the results returning as as JSON string you can [read up on JSON here](http://www.w3schools.com/json/default.asp).

In your webpage, make the request with javascript & ajax. Basically, when the user clicks a button, send the info asynchronously to your php script, and when the response is received display the inf to the user. You can [read up on Javascript & Ajax here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp).